# GraphQL Module - Run middleware for all operations except public ones

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-modules

I started working with [GraphQL Modules](https://www.graphql-modules.com/docs/advanced/middlewares/), and they introduce the concept of middlewares, in which you can apply at different levels.

I configured a middleware for my whole application like this to require authentication:

```
export const modularApp = createApplication({
    modules: [customerModule, premiumModule],
    middlewares: {
        "*": {
            "*": [authMiddleware],
        },
    },
});

export function authMiddleware({ root, args, context, info }, next) {
  if (context.authenticated) {
    throw new AuthenticationError("Unauthorized");
  }
  return next();
}
```

However there are a few queries and mutations that I'd like to bypass the `authMiddleware`, because they are public. I thought adding them on the module level would override the application middleware:

```
export default createModule({
  id: 'customer-module',
  dirname: __dirname,
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  middlewares: {
    'Query': {
      'somePublicOperation': [publicMiddleware],
    }
  },
});

export function publicMiddleware({ root, args, context, info }, next) {
  // bypass authMiddleware
  return next();
}
```

Both middlewares are executed instead, so I can't figure a solution for this issue.

I could add the `authMiddleware` individually to operations, but that's not very scalable as most operations require auth. Another idea is creating separate modules for public/protected operations, but I'm not sure what is the performance impact since both rely on the same types.